# `azure site list` throws TypeError

Tags: command-line-interface, azure

Steps:

```
azure account download
azure account import MyFile      (where MyFile is the downloaded publish file)
azure account list               (output is normal and correct)
azure site list
info:    Executing command site list
- Getting locationsinfo:    Executing command site list
+
+ Getting locations
| Getting locationserror:   Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
info:    Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\Me\.azure\azure.err
```

error:   site list command failed

The file `azure.err` looks like this:

```
Thu Jul 02 2015 11:57:52 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time):
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined]
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\commands\asm\site._js:72:21
    at Interactor.__.extend.formatOutput (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\util\interaction.js:248:7)
    at AzureCli.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\commands\asm\site._js:71:27)
    at AzureCli.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\cli.js:216:12)
    at AzureCli.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\node_modules\commander\lib\commander.js:235:8)
    at AzureCli.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at AzureCli.Command.parseArgs (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\node_modules\commander\lib\commander.js:405:12)
    at AzureCli.Command.parse (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\node_modules\commander\lib\commander.js:351:15)
    at AzureCli.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\cli.js:510:20)
    at AzureCli.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

Any idea why this is happening?